# Windows 10 start menu shutdown button not doing anything

Tags: shutdown, system-restore, windows-10-v1607

I recently got the Anniversary Update for Windows 10 and it was working fine for a while, but now whenever I try to use the shut down option from the Start menu it doesn't do anything at all (as in no action happens, no logout and no black screen),  I have to force shutdown by holding the power button. I tried to refresh my PC but even that doesn't work from settings, and booting into advanced startup and trying to refresh my PC from there also doesn't work (because holding shift and pressing restart also doesn't do anything). The Sleep option works, however.

I ran `sfc /scannow` as admin on command prompt but it returned that there were no errors



Windows 10 on Acer with Intel core i7 2.4GHz and NVidia 920M GPU

Comment: Try running `sfc.exe /scannow` as admin through command prompt...

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow I tried that but it returned that no errors were found

Comment: Nothing in the logs? Can you output info on your system? (OS, specs) Know it's not really necessary, but gives a _little_ to go off.

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow Updated the question. I tried using msconfig to start up without any 3rd party applications, but the issue remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a "work around" although I'd still love to get instruction on rehabbing the customary Restart/Sleep/Shutdown choice display. (Anyone?)

Just RIGHT-click the lower left corner Windows icon; a sub-menu appears on which one choice is "Shut down or sign out."  Left click that line and a sub-sub-menu appears with the customary Restart/Sleep/Shutdown choices.

Comment: doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this from experience, but it may not rectify your fault. The first step to perform is to open up an *elevated* Powershell and run the following:

`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}`

Reboot your PC and test your start menu. (This code/command is somewhere on the internet, easily found)

If this fix does not work, add another user to your PC -

`net user username /add`

Rerun the original command.

**Update - Powershell Error**

Firstly, I would suggest trying to boot into Safe Mode and attempt to run the command.

Make the `*.ps1` locally (`C:\tmp\win_10.ps1` as an example).

Set the execution policy to unsigned, `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` and then attempt to execute the PowerShell script.

If that does not work, from Command Prompt run: `powershell -noexit & “C:\tmp\*.ps1”`... the only other thing I could suggest would be [Update your PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902239/how-to-upgrade-powershell-version-from-2-0-to-3-0) and hope for the best...

**Note:** In command prompt, type `powershell.exe` to convert.

Comment: Could I run this through Command Prompt as Admin? Windows Powershell isn't displaying any text I type

Comment: Open Command Prompt as Admin, then type Powershell - work? This is a powershell app. Else, make a ps1 then try to execute it.

Comment: The command prompt doesn't return anything, and the ps1 does the same http://imgur.com/FfeDhoo

Comment: Could I just disable Developer Mode from settings?

Comment: @TheBigFootsDad I am not 100%, give it a go and let me know :) Updated answer also.

Comment: The error where there is simply a blinking underscore still comes up in command prompt. I will try making a new user and running it from there. 
Also windows powershell is the newest version

Comment: Ok so I disabled developer mode and the powershell isn't working, and it isn't working from a different user as well.

Comment: @TheBigFootsDad With all the faults you're having I would suggest a refresh of windows 10 :)

Comment: I've tried but the button in the start menu and the one in advanced startup does nothing

Comment: I'm going to try a complete reinstall of windows